# Wrong in my guard expression?

Tags: haskell, guard

I am writing a small program which "builds up" a string from another string (which is the "input string"(parameter)). However I am getting a parse error(on input '='). I suspect I am doing something wrong with my guard expression ?

```
checkCons :: Char -> Bool 
checkCons x = notElem x ['a','e','i','o','u','y'] 


rovarSprak :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
rovarSprak [] res = res
rovarSprak (c:restOfStr) res
    | (checkCons c) == True  =  rovarSprak restOfStr (c:'o':c:res)
    | otherwise = rovarSprak restOfStr (c:res)
```

If I make the call: `rovarSprak "abc" []` . I expect `"abobcoc"`.

Observe that the `checkCons` function is working as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your old code was not properly indented. If I run the `ghc` compiler on:

```
rovarSprak :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
rovarSprak [] res = res
rovarSprak (c:restOfStr) res
| (checkCons c) == True  =  rovarSprak restOfStr (c:'o':c:res)
| otherwise = rovarSprak restOfStr (c:res)
```

it gives an error:

```
strep.hs:8:1: parse error on input ‘|’
```

rewriting this to:

```
rovarSprak :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
rovarSprak [] res = res
rovarSprak (c:restOfStr) res
    | (checkCons c) == True  =  rovarSprak restOfStr (c:'o':c:res)
    | otherwise = rovarSprak restOfStr (c:res)
```

solves the compile error.

Furthermore If  try to reproduce it, the result is:

```
"cocboba"
```

The guards are working fine, the only problem with your code is that in the recursive call:

```
rovarSprak restOfStr (c:'o':c:res)
--                   ^push in front
```

you push the result in front of the new list whereas you probably want it to be at the tail.

You can solve this by not working with an *accumulator*, but emitting elements straight away. For example:

```
rovarSprak :: [Char] -> [Char]
rovarSprak [] = []
rovarSprak (c:restOfStr)
    | (checkCons c) == True =  c : 'o' : c : (rovarSprak restOfStr)
    | otherwise = c : rovarSprak restOfStr
```

(emission in boldface and stroke redundant code elements). This also allows lazy list generation: perhaps you are only interested in the first three elements of the output, or perhaps the input is an infinite list.

A final optimization I propose is to swap the two lines of `rovarSprak`:

```
rovarSprak :: [Char] -> [Char]
rovarSprak (c:restOfStr)
    | checkCons c =  c : 'o' : c : (rovarSprak restOfStr)
    | otherwise = c : rovarSprak restOfStr
rovarSprak [] = []
```

this is because it is more likely you will have a match on the first line: for a list with length *N* there will be *N* calls on the first pattern and *one* on the second pattern.

Comment: @J.doe: did you intended your code probably as in the edit? Otherwise there is probably an element in the code you forgot to mention.

Comment: The problem is ,which could not be seen from my example code (since it was edited), that emacs is not indenting the guards(and I can't even tabulate ), in facts my guards are aligned with: rovarsprak - is this why I am getting a parse error ? and not "cocboba" @Willem Van Onsem

Comment: The "final optimization" will do precisely nothing. GHC *always* rearranges patterns to match the order in which the constructors are *defined*. Yes, this is sometimes unfortunate, but it is the way it is at present.

Comment: @dfeuer: Who says one uses ghc? I can build my own unintelligent Haskell compiler. As always you can rely on the compiler to see optimizations, but it is always better to perform some optimizations yourself (although premature optimization is the root of some evil ;).

Comment: When performing micro-optimizations like re-ordering patterns, one must *always* target a specific implementation and family of hardware architectures. Otherwise, one is wasting one's time for sure!

Comment: @dfeuer: well evidently you have to make some assumptions on how the compiler *will* behave. For instance for Prolog it will conceptually enumerate over the declarations in the order of definition. That does not mean the SWI-Prolog system will do this of course. Where do you read in this question the OP wants a GHC specific answer?

Comment: ok it was just some minor mistake with emacs. Anyhow thanks, I am just learning haskell from start so I will read your other suggestion more closely